# JavaScript running order questions

Tags: javascript, closures

I have a very simple Javascript code, can't fully understand the running order and output.

```
function f1() {

    n = 999;

    change = function() {
        n = "Barry";
    };
    return change;

}

var result = f1();

result(); 
console.log(n)
change();
console.log(n)
```

Output:

```
Barry
Barry
```

As my understand, I define a globale variable n, and n = 999.
Then I create a function which will define globale n to "Barry". and assign this function to change. and return this change variable.

Then I trigger this f1(), and give change to result. At this timepoint the change is a function but not runs yet.

So why the first Console.log return my **Barry**? Then change has not runs yet..

Comment: go ahead and ask yourself "what is the point of returning `change` if it is a global variable?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not properly declaring your variables in the scope with either `var`, `let` or `const` so it is polluting the global or outer scopes.

`n` is changed because `result === change` and `change` sets `n` to `Barry`.

Comment: Please, I know it is not properly way to set up in the environment. I just want to know the reason of this bahaive.

Comment: @PEIRANLIU read the 2nd paragraph - thats why. also you can use a debugger to follow the flow of the code.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, I got that result ===change, but change is a variable when I return it. Is that auto runs the functions when I return it?

Comment: @PEIRANLIU you do call `result`

Comment: emm.. Since I called result(), then f1() is called. and it return me a function that set n to barry..... But.... is that called this anoymous function? I was think it just return the function without running it...

Comment: You did! But after you call f1 you call result

Answer (score 1):

The reason for this behavior is at this line ,

```
var result = f1(); // n - 999
```

At this point you are calling the inner function and setting the n to Barry

```
result(); // n - Barry
```

I am not sure how you calling this function directly. But hope it's just a pseudo code

```
change(); // n - Barry
```

Which means,

```
 result() === change()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I fully understand it now.

Answer (score 1):

> why the first Console.log return my Barry? Then change has not runs yet..

Yes it has, you are only calling `console.log` after having called `result()`. Try the following:

```js
var n, change;
function f1() {

    n = 999;

    change = function() {
        n = "Barry";
    };
    return change;

}

console.log(n);
var result = f1();
console.log(result === change);
console.log(n);
result(); 
console.log(n);
change();
console.log(n);
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I understand it now.!

Answer (score 1):

When you call the result function, here is the sequence.

```
function f1(){
  //declares n variable
  //declares change function
  //return change function, and calls it, at this point it changes n to "barry".
}
```

Comment: Got it , thank you so much!